# should I wrapper the redis incr in a distributed lock?

Tags: redis

I have an application with many clients may concurrency call incr on same key .
should I worry about it?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you just call incr on the key, and not get+set at the same time, locking is not required. Redis serializes all commands (including incr), since it is a single-threaded event loop. You can consider that execution of all individual commands is atomic.